# Python post requests return response 400

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, graphql, data-mining

[[image: Here is the API which I want to scrape.][1]]

I am trying to scrape This website https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/818583073/dies-irae-day-of-wrath-rated-r/ and when I send a post requests to its API it just return response 400 and empty content.

Here is my code.

```
import requests


url = 'https://www.kickstarter.com/graph'
headers =  {'authority':'www.kickstarter.com',
'method':'POST',
'path':'/graph',
'scheme':'https',
'accept':'*/*',
'accept-encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
'accept-language':'en-US,en;q=0.9',
'content-length':'606',
'content-type':'application/json',
'cookie':"vis=f5761fb0e1994852-b38b5b3d46161036-c3a4a56c5add1076v1; lang=en; woe_id=YzFrZ1NUV1lRTUhMT2tsc1ZURHVsQT09LS12L0pidVVCeDBHZU16dk81MmVpeTNBPT0%3D--468e7c1e5daf8c17cdd902b0a1cb1ef4e2856543; optimizely_current_variations=%7B%7D; _pxhd=75f70796791b6f8a5930b19c70bcd30d268fe4a4f1644460c7c7bbe65d5e8196:837ba981-9d56-11eb-841e-e7065f1f0101; _pxvid=837ba981-9d56-11eb-841e-e7065f1f0101; ajs_anonymous_id=%22f5761fb0e1994852-b38b5b3d46161036-c3a4a56c5add1076v1%22; _ga=GA1.2.17378398.1618428050; _gid=GA1.2.1258279558.1618428050; __ssid=3d59a55ffedce2904d3464e3a555309; em_cdn_uid=t%3D1618428051657%26u%3D8d620439ed7740b89c98770bbaee8b05; __stripe_mid=e4e89c20-83c7-4ba0-907b-7b83f8b24051e87f22; em_p_uid=l:1618428053354|t:1618428053353|u:c814f9e5a157438b910a57075a7fe320; __stripe_sid=eaa7f9e2-2ba2-45db-8213-c79be847d1100aa907; ajs_anonymous_id=%22f5761fb0e1994852-b38b5b3d46161036-c3a4a56c5add1076v1%22; _px2=eyJ1IjoiZTQ0MTZhZjAtOWRjNi0xMWViLWE0M2MtYjM2ODk4NjhlZTYxIiwidiI6IjgzN2JhOTgxLTlkNTYtMTFlYi04NDFlLWU3MDY1ZjFmMDEwMSIsInQiOjE2MTg0NzY4NTU0MjQsImgiOiIwYzI2NWVlOTAzY2U1NWM1MGI4ODhmZTFkZmMxYTZhYmMzYmVkYzU5ZDQ4OTA3ZDg4NGEzZjA0NDBmN2RjNTczIn0=; last_page=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.kickstarter.com%2Fprojects%2F818583073%2Fdies-irae-day-of-wrath-rated-r%2Fdescription; _ksr_session=THQxSGRqa3FabnRmV1V5Wk9sbStaV1ltSWlTcTIzc3hBTFJYeXN0TnpTMEJYK2lZN3VIS3pTakhkeTlRL2VxNWJNT2svZkFabjFNeFB6aG1YaEwrNjR6WCtIZGxUamF2TEdOK2YvOS8yQjJseWtvajVtUHZDcVBoa3JVOTBHSFFoSjg4WFdzUllRblJubUM0bnVlak9nPT0tLVlXS1M5R3pYNVZtcjllZklGVWNiL2c9PQ%3D%3D--962d5221d168b9e73b4769f2a39314c747fe24bf; request_time=Thu%2C+15+Apr+2021+08%3A52%3A59+-0000; local_offset=-2333",
'origin':'https://www.kickstarter.com',
'referer':'https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/818583073/dies-irae-day-of-wrath-rated-r/description',
'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36',
'x-csrf-token':'tQoXSUK0yYY+5r6bgZH3i3Pfya96S6S6ZcOmh/6qRea0XLl1c6ZX6Asmm3vrtenqxOKacQi1tKTN0c9OxRJyoA=='
}

payload = {
    'operationName':'Campaign',
    'query':'query Campaign($slug: String!) {↵  project(slug: $slug) {↵    id↵    isSharingProjectBudget↵    risks↵    story(assetWidth: 680)↵    currency↵    spreadsheet {↵      displayMode↵      public↵      url↵      data {↵        name↵        value↵        phase↵        rowNum↵        __typename↵      }↵      dataLastUpdatedAt↵      __typename↵    }↵    environmentalCommitments {↵      id↵      commitmentCategory↵      description↵      __typename↵    }↵    __typename↵  }↵}↵',
    'variables':{
        'slug':'818583073/dies-irae-day-of-wrath-rated-r'
    }
}

r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)


print(r.status_code)
print(r.content)



400
''
```

Comment: The `x-csrf-token` header will likely have to be different for every request...

Answer (score 0):

you have set content type as json in headers

change it to `'Content-Type':'text/html'` it will work

Comment: it just return this {'errors': [{'message': 'No query string was present'}]}

Comment: @MalikIbrahim Now the bad request error is solved. you have to debug and prepare proper payload with query and try again. You might need to check the API doc for this particular API

Comment: will you plz help me I tried but nothing found.